# Как найти любой спецсимвол по регулярному выражению?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как мне создать запрос чтобы найти любые спецсимволы, прописывать их все или есть какой-то шаблон?
Просто такой я не нашел, только максимум допустим из такой фразы "Бастилия" по мотивам картины К. Коровина
чтобы убрать первые спецсимволы, чтобы отсортировалась это

```
/\"/
```

Но вдруг будет там не такие ковычки а другие или какой-то другой спецсимвол, то как проще сделать? чтобы не писать `/\"\'.../`

Comment: Дело в том, что понятие "спецсимвол" в RE не определено. Поэтому ответ зависит от того, что́ вы понимаете под этим словом. Если всё, что не буква и не цифра, то, опять же, сразу надо уточнять "не буква какого из поддерживаемых Юникодом алфавитов?", то есть обрабатывать ли, к примеру, грузинские и армянские буквы как буквы или как спецсимволы. И.т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо вам нужно такое регулярное выражение:

```
/[^\s\w\dа-яА-ЯёЁ]/g
```

Проверить можете [тут](https://regex101.com/r/rAeIn5/4)